# Java - Import .csv to database - Exclude last row

Tags: java, sql, database, csv, import

I'm importing database values from a .csv file. However, the last row in the .csv is actually the totals of some columns, and my importer updates the database with that being the last row and that is undesirable. And that messes up the queries that I'll do later with it. Please help how can I prevent this?

My code of my .csv importer:

```
try
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("v.csv"));
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        String[]value = line.split(",");
        String sql = "INSERT into main ([Ticket #], Status, Priority, Department, [Account Name]) "
                + "values ('"+value[0]+"','"+value[1]+"','"+value[2]+"','"+value[3]+"','"+value[4]+"')";
        System.out.println(sql);
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        try
        {
            pst = db.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        }finally{
            if(pst != null){
                pst.close();
            }
        }
    }
    br.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("v.csv"));
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        lines.Add(line);
    }
    br.close();
    if (lines.size() > 1) { // be sure that the last row exists (prevents indexoutexception)
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size() - 1; i++) { // the - 1 excludes the last row
            String[]value = lines.get(i).split(",");
            String sql = "INSERT into main ([Ticket #], Status, Priority, Department, [Account Name]) "
                    + "values ('"+value[0]+"','"+value[1]+"','"+value[2]+"','"+value[3]+"','"+value[4]+"')";
            System.out.println(sql);
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            try
            {
                pst = db.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.executeUpdate();
            } finally {
                if(pst != null) {
                    pst.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can use the Apache commons IO ReversedLinesFileReader and read the CSV from the end. Then you can skip the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("v.csv"));
    String line;
    String firstFlag =true;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
     if (!firstFlag){

    String sql = "INSERT into main ([Ticket #], Status, Priority, Department, [Account      Name]) "
            + "values      ('"+value[0]+"','"+value[1]+"','"+value[2]+"','"+value[3]+"','"+value[4]+"')";
        System.out.println(sql);
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        try
        {
            pst = db.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        }finally{
            if(pst != null){
                pst.close();
            }
        }
 }
     String[]value = line.split(",");
     firstFlag=false;
    }
     br.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```